# Ionic 2 click event inside infowindow googlemaps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, ionic2, infowindow

Hi i'm trying to fire an event from a button inside a google maps infowindow.
the problem is that i can´t make it fire by any mean.

```
addMarket(latitud, longitud, sensorData) {

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: false,
  position: { lat: latitud, lng: longitud },
  map: this.map,//set map created here
  title: sensorData.sensor
});
marker.addListener('click', function () {
  infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
});

let bodyMessege = 'Nombre del Sensor: ' + sensorData.sensor + '<br>' +
  'Componente Descripcion: ' + sensorData.componentDesc + '<br>' +
  ' description:  ' + sensorData.description + '<br>' +
  ' Tipo de sensor: ' + sensorData.type + '<br>' +
  ' Unidad de sensor: ' + sensorData.unit + '<br>' +
  'Tipo de dato: ' + sensorData.dataType + '<br>' +
  '  <button ion-button (click)="this.navCtrl.push(DetalleSensorPage)" >Default</button>';

//      ' <button ion-button=""  onclick=console.log("log");'  anda
//this.pushPage=DetalleSensorPage;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: bodyMessege
});
```

Any tip will be welcome thanks. :)

Comment: I was able to solve it, but I'm not sure if it's the same scenario. On my end the requirement was to only show _one info view at the time_ and include a button inside of it. So if you first open an info view, and then you click on another marker, the first info view will be closed and only the new one will be shown. Would that be ok?

Comment: It's the same requirement only one popup will show at a time, when a marker is pressed an infowindow shows information and has a button to redirect to another page, showing more details. I tried calling a function from the button, but I can't get even a console log to work.

Comment: If it is helpful you can [look at my code](https://github.com/philipbrack/paystumped_ionic2fullapp/blob/master/src/pages/map-content/map-content.ts) for a similar implementation where I open InfoWindow when a region of a map is clicked.  FYI this is also an Ionic 2 app.

Answer (score 8):

I have found this solution for my own project: ( https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ng-click-in-google-maps-infowindow/5537/6)

The key element is the id="tap" that you look for at the getElementbyId below.

```
let content = '<div class="infowindow"><p id="tap">your text here</p></div>';

let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  {
    closeBoxURL: "",
    content: content
  }
);
infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
  document.getElementById('tap').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //alert('Clicked');
    console.log("touch");
    this.closeInfoViewWindow(infoWindow);
    this.openEventDetailModal(event);
  });
});
```

hope this will help you and others.